# Equivalent of SQL exists in Kotlin Exposed

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

What is the equivalent of SQL `exists` in Kotlin Exposed?

Comment: Isn't there an `exists(Something.id eq SomethingElse.id)` (for example) in Kotlin Exposed? [This site](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL) states that `exists` is valid in a `where`, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Is called the same in Exposed: `org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.exists` as seen [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#where-expression).